# Написать 301 редирект в htacces при смене движка (переменная после знака вопроса)

Tags: редирект, .htaccess, redirect

Привет!

Меняю движок сайта с неудобоваримой польской кракозяблы на opencart, нужен 301-редирект. На польском движке ссылка имеет вид: `http://site.org/?XX,tovar_dlya_rebenka` где "XX"- переменная, состоящая из двух цифр (номер товара, на разных товарах разный: 56, 49 и т.п., так как движок хранит данные в php).

На опенкарте ссылка будет `http://site.org/katalog/tovar_dlya_rebenka.html`.

**Обновление**

Сделал так:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?26,tovar_dlya_rebenka_32popugaya-vmeste
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.org/katalog/kupit_nabor_32_popugaya? [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^?27,tovar_dlya_rebenka_kran_50cm
RewriteRule (.*) http://site.org/katalog/kupit_tovar_dlya_rebenka_kran_50cm? [L,R=301]
```

Но, будет ли так правильно?

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^[0-9]{2},(.*)
RewriteRule .* http://site.ru/%1.html? [R=301,L]
```

Здесь вместо %1 подставится выражение которое будет попадать в круглые скобки в первой строке. То есть туда попадет всё что будет после двух цифр и запятой. Далее вроде всё ясно.